# How to clear the screen in gcc?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am using code block and gcc for my C as i am a begineer how do i clear the screen the function

```
clrscr();
```

is not working

Comment: the question already has answered -- but "is not working" is very vague. Next time,you need provide things such error message(from compiler),compiler's name,platform,arch etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following should work on most systems:

```
system("clear");
```

or

```
 system("tput clear");
```

Comment: Code::Blocks is a cross-platform IDE and you have, with one fell swoop, single-platformed the executables it generates :-) In any case, it would possibly be better to access the terminfo stuff directly from  C rather than having to spawn a separate executable to do it for you.

Comment: You can consider too print several new lines as most `clear`-like programs does.

Comment: @jack after printing the pointer must be on top left corner would you expain how you would do this